# Sanitize string to start only with _, -, $ or letter & the rest can only have those characters

Tags: php, regex, string, replace

How can I write a regex that only converts a standard string consisting of any characters to only start with `_`,`-`,`$`, or a non-accented letter, and the rest of the string can only have those characters or non-accented letters?

I can get all non-numeric with `preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z]/", "", $value)` but that isn't what I need.

What I want to do is take a string that might initial be to take this string
`4_The quick brown fox jumps o8ver the lazy dog and the slow white dog fox jumps over the unlazy fox.` and turn it into `_Thequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydogandtheslowwhitedogfoxjumpsovertheunlazyfox`

Comment: ok @anubhava I've a sample of what I've done

Comment: Question is unclear.  Examples would be helpful.

Comment: @rgbflawed I have an example there

Comment: Like this? `(?:^[^_$a-zA-Z-]+|[^$\w-]+)`  https://regex101.com/r/jQCqch/1

Answer (score 0):

The following pattern will remove one or more characters that are not on the whitelist of hyphens, underscores, dollar signs, or letters.

It is not necessary to specify the start of the string when the same sanitization is used throughout the string.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/tFGi7))

```
$string = '4_The quick brown fox jumps o8ver the lazy dog and the slow white dog fox jumps over the unlazy fox.';

var_export(
    preg_replace(
        '~[^-_$a-z]+~i',
        '',
        $string
    )
);
```

Output:

```
'_Thequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydogandtheslowwhitedogfoxjumpsovertheunlazyfox'
```